# How can I restart a for loop after that it ended in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following function:

```
def spell_checker(w):
     correzione = []
     limite = 2
     for word in frequenza():
         res = edit_distance(word.lower(), w)
        if word not in correzione:
              if res == 0: 
              correzione.append(w)
              break
        if res > 0 and res < limite: 
           correzione.append(word)

return correzione
```

So what I need to do is: when the for loop ends, if the list *correzione* is empty, I want to increment *limite* by one, and start again the loop.

if I put limite += 1 within the loop, it increases any time the list is empty, but I need it only if at the end of everything it is empty.

it could be something like:

```
if len(correzione) == 0:
    limite += 1
for word in frequenza():
    #same loop as before
```

But this is way too redundant!

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the place to use _functions_.

Comment: You can use recrusion.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple you can use a while loop to keep working until the list is not empty :

```
    def spell_checker(w):
    correzione = []
    limite = 2
    while len(correzione) == 0:
        for word in frequenza():
            res = edit_distance(word.lower(), w)
            if word not in correzione:
                if res == 0: 
                    correzione.append(w)
                    break
            if res > 0 and res < limite: 
                correzione.append(word)
        if len(correzione) == 0:
            limite += 1
    return correzione
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was proposed by @Megalng, the recursion seems quite reasonable in this case. Something like this probably:

```
from edit_distance import edit_distance


MAX_LIMIT = 10


def frequenza():
    return ['first', 'second', 'third']


def spell_checker(w, limite=1):
    global MAX_LIMIT
    if limite > MAX_LIMIT:
        raise RuntimeError('Stack overflow!')

    correzione = []

    for word in frequenza():
        res = edit_distance(word.lower(), w)

        if word not in correzione:
            if res == 0:
                correzione.append(w)
                break

        if 0 < res < limite:
            correzione.append(word)

    if not correzione:
        return spell_checker(limite + 1)
    return correzione


def main():
    print(spell_checker('awordofmine'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sure enough, you can use classes instead of global variables, or somehow else handle your limit like return `None` if it is acceptable to just give up.